# Search for input parameters to the GetPrintAtlas method

Tags: qgis, qgis-server

How is it possible to find the parameters sent to the GetPrintAtlas method from the atlas, such as EXP_FILTER?

Request example:

```
[https://****?SERVICE=WMS&VERSION=1.3.0&REQUEST=GetPrintAtlas&EXP_FILTER=id+IN+(%27503%27%2C%27590%27%2C%27990%27%2C%275336%27%2C%275337%27)&TEMPLATE=Stampa+Area&filtertoken=&DOWNLOAD=1]
```